# Styling a Derived UserControl causes it to disappear

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a control `PaneBase`, which derives from `UserControl`. There is no XAML, it's just a control. The `UserControl` type in question is the one from Catel, but I still observe this issue when using `System.Windows.Controls.UserControl`.

```
public class PaneBase : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title",
                                    typeof(string),
                                    typeof(PaneBase),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string Title
    {
        get => (string) GetValue(TitleProperty);
        set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
    }
}
```

I have another control `EquationPane` which derives from `PaneBase` and does have XAML:

**EquationPane.xaml**

```
<local:PaneBase x:Class="EngineersToolkit.Windows.Views.Panes.EquationPane"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:catel="http://schemas.catelproject.com" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EngineersToolkit.Windows.Views.Panes"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                Title="Equation"
                d:DataContext="{d:DesignData EquationPaneViewModel}" d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
                mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Width="150" Height="30"
                 Text="{Binding Equation, Mode=TwoWay}" />

    </Grid>
</local:PaneBase>
```

**EquationPane.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class EquationPane
{
    public EquationPane()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new EquationPaneViewModel();
    }
}
```

All of this works so far, when I include an `EquationPane` in a window, then it shows up normally:

```
<Grid>
    <panes:EquationPane Width="100" Height="100"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Background="Aqua" />

</Grid>
```

[image]

It continues to work properly if I attempt to style the control:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type panes:EquationPane}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

However, things begin to fall apart if I target the style to `PaneBase` instead. If I change `TargetType` to PaneBase, then the style is simply not applied. However, if I override the dependency property metadata in `PaneBase` like this:

```
static PaneBase()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(PaneBase),
                                             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                                 typeof(PaneBase)));
}
```

Then the control ceases to render at all, leaving me with a blank window. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

WPF controls are "lookless" which means that they have no appearance unless you define a template for them.

The following indicates that there is a default style defined for `PaneBase` in `themes/generic.xaml`:

```
static PaneBase()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(PaneBase),
                                         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                             typeof(PaneBase)));
}
```

You should then define such a style:

```
<Style TargetType="local:PaneBase">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you remove the static constructor in `PanelBase` it will inherit the template from the style of the `UserControl` base class.

If you then define a `Style` for `PaneBase` like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PaneBase}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

...it no longer has a template and that's why you don't see the control in your window.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit Styles are not automatically applied to the derived types. To apply the style of PaneBase to EquationPane, you can do one of the following:

1.Write this on your EquationPane.xaml.cs

```
public EquationPane() 
    {
        this.SetResourceReference(StyleProperty, typeof(PaneBase));
    }
```

2.Explicitly provide the style where EquationPane is used

```
<panes:EquationPane Style="{DynamicResource {x:Type PaneBase}}"/>
```

3.Define a style that is basedon the parent style

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type PaneBase}" TargetType="{x:Type PaneBase}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type panes:EquationPane}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type PaneBase}}"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure I have to do this? Targeting the style to `PaneBase` was specifically so that I could avoid doing this.

Comment: Yes. What you are trying to do does not even work for derived controls from wpf controls. You will have to explicitly define their styles.